# Java 8 type inference involving Booleans

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, java-8, type-inference

Consider the following code:

```
class Predicate {
    public boolean eval(EvaluationContext ec) { /* logic here */ }
}

// later ...
List<Predicate> preds = new List<>( /* some predicates here */ );

// now let's use Stream<> to implement the AND logical connective:
// VERSION A:
Boolean resultA = preds.stream()
                       .map(p -> p.eval(context))
                       .reduce(Boolean.TRUE, (a,b) -> Boolean.logicalAnd(a,b));
// Oops: the code above doesn't compile ...   
// Error: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to boolean

// VERSION B:   (add an intermediate variable with explicit type)
Stream<Boolean> v = _children.stream().map(p -> p.eval(context));
Boolean resultB = v.reduce(Boolean.TRUE, (a,b) -> Boolean.logicalAnd(a, b) );
// compiles just fine...
```

So, my question is:

What is wrong with the structure of Version A that prevents the Java compiler from correctly inferring the type of the result of map()? Is this a limitation of the type-inference algorithm in Java? If so, is there a better way to write this code so that the type inference succeeds?

Comment: Both work for me in Eclipse.

Comment: Additional clarification: This is using javac version 1.8.0_25 running under the OpenJDK.

Comment: Can you put a full example? (Like no `new List`, showing what `_children` is, etc.) It works for 1.8.0_20 Oracle JDK too.

Comment: To address your final question, I would probably use `preds.stream().allMatch(p -> p.eval(context))`.

Comment: Works for me on 8u25, Windows 7 x64. What platform do you use? Also, please add compilable example.

Comment: It's possible that version A fails because OpenJDK doesn't realize it needs to autobox `p.eval(context)` into a Boolean object before the reduce() operation. The streams don't handle conversion between objects and primitives well, which is why there are mapToInt, mapToLong, and mapToDouble functions and separate implementations for primitive streams. Perhaps you can try explicitly casting: `.map(p -> (Boolean) p.eval(context))`

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles fine with `jdk1.8.0_05`, `jdk1.8.0_20`, `jdk1.8.0_25`, and `jdk1.8.0_40 (beta)` and there’s no reason to assume that there is another version having problems with it. Maybe it helps when you either fix the other errors of your made-up code or post the real code you gave to the compiler.

E.g. you can’t say `new List<>` if `List` refers to `java.util.List` and your example code contains no declaration of `context`. If `context` cannot be found, the compiler will indeed produce an “incompatible types” follow-up error which will disappear once you fixed the other errors. It’s striking that your second example uses `_children` rather than `preds` so it originates from a different context where most probably no such compiler errors exist.

By the way, your lambda expression `(a,b) -> Boolean.logicalAnd(a,b)` is a bit odd. Either use expressions, e.g. `(a,b) -> a && b` or a method reference like `Boolean::logicalAnd`.

But either way, using reduction is not recommended. You can get a better performance by using short-circuiting methods, e.g. `_children.stream().allMatch(p -> p.eval(context))` for `logical and` or `_children.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.eval(context))` for `logical or`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't just AND all your predicates together using

```
Predicate<EvaluationContext> finalTest = preds.stream()
                                              .reduce(((p)->true), Predicate::and);
```

Then you have one predicate, and you can save and reuse it to test any number of contexts after compiling it only once.

After re-reading, I noticed that your Predicate class is not a java.util.function.Predicate. In order to do what I describe, you need to alter YOUR Predicate class slightly to make it implement the Predicate interface:

```
public class Predicate implements java.util.function.Predicate<EvaluationContext>{
    public boolean eval(EvaluationContext ec) { /* logic here */ }

    @Override
    public boolean test(EvaluationContext t) {
        return eval(t);
    }
}
```